# Problem with using https://allorigins.win/ to Pass Cors when my link has parameters in it

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to use this [website](https://allorigins.win/#raw_39)'s service **raw?url=** API but there is problem when my own link contains a few parameters. example:

```
api: https://api.allorigins.win/raw?url=
destination: https://nocors2.glitch.me/webm?a=b&c=d
```

Seems they will confuse the link's parameters as the API's parameters when requesting.
I would like to know if you can think of any solution I can pass this problem?

I need a service to let me pass Cors restriction without making my own server, so far this website was the best that's why I would like to solve this.

Comment: URL Encode your url

Comment: @SubirKumarSao wow, thank you, how stupid can i be . thanks again

Comment: Indeed, the examples on that same page demonstrate the use of `encodeURIComponent` to do just that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode your URL since it's a parameter. See [RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986) for more details.

For *JavaScript*, this would be:

```
"https://api.allorigins.win/raw?url=" + encodeURIComponent("https://nocors2.glitch.me/webm?a=b&c=d");
```